# Custom class font-size not working in Tailwind CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, tailwind-css, font-size

I have defined a custom class called `.myclass` in the `<style>` tag with a `font-size` of `10rem`. However, the font size of the `h1` element with the `.myclass` and `text-3xl` classes is not being set to `10rem` as expected. Can someone please explain why this is happening and suggest a solution?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
</head>
<style>
    .myclass{
        font-size: 10rem;
    }
</style>
<body>
  <h1 class="myclass text-3xl font-bold underline">
    Hello world!
  </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

I expected the `h1` element with both the `.myclass` and `text-3xl` classes to have a font size of `10rem`. However, the font size of the `h1` element was not being set to `10rem` as expected, and I was unsure why this was happening.

Comment: if you see in devtools tailwind class text-3xl is applied and it doesn't gives you size of 10 rem. text-3xl gives you size around 1.875rem not 10 rem

Comment: you can remove this text-3xl tailwind class if you need 10 rem from your custom class which is '.myclass' or either configure tailwind for 10 rem

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I tried removing the `text-3xl` class from the `h1` element and it did work to set the font size to `10rem` using my custom class `.myclass`. However, as you mentioned, I have many pages in my project and it is not feasible to remove the `text-3xl` class from all relevant elements. 

Is there any easy way that I can just change font-size of all classes in a container.

Comment: Sure, if you want to change text-3xl class pointing to 10 rem for that you will have to customize or you can create new configuration like text-10xl. You are using simple HTML CSS and JS so the first answer shared below won't work, you need to add your custom configuration in a script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Add this script in Head or Body tag**

```js
<script>
    tailwind.config = {
      theme: {
        extend: {
          fontSize: {
            '3xl': '10rem',
          }
        }
      }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:** Remove `.text-3xl` class. The text-size will be fully rely on `.myclass` class.

**Option 2:** You can change the configuration of Tailwind to use `10rem` for the `.text-3xl` class.

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontSize: {
        '3xl': '10rem',
      },
    },
  },
  variants: {},
  plugins: [],
}
```

Comment: I have added in my script below the cdn but it is also not working!